# Как удалить файл из директории на Си?

Tags: c

Как удалить файл из директории D:\Files\1.txt на Си?
без сообщений и подтверждений

```
#include < stdio.h >  // Для printf, remove

int main (void)
{    
   printf (“Удаление файла: ”);
   // Удаление файла
   if (-1 == remove (“test.txt”))
      printf (“Ошибка\n”);
   else 
      printf (“Выполнено\n”);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так так и удалить -

```
remove("D:\\Files\\1.txt");
```

Если права доступа позволяют, файл не открыт никем, атрибута ReadOnly нет - удалится без сообщений и подтверждений :)

Comment: Harry, можете написать полностью код? который сразу можно откомпилировать... очень нужно:)

Comment: Ну так вот же он - `remove("D:\\Files\\1.txt");`...

Comment: в коде что удалить и что добавить чтобы просто компилировать в .exe тот что я выше Вам представила в вопросе)

Comment: @Eva, pastebin.com вас ждёт.